# Acces Denied Another Shared Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in my MVC project ,I want to save image to the shared folder  on the another IP .
Shared folder have been given to 'Everyone' permission. But I get error Access Denied. What other permissions should be granted? Could you help me?

My codes;

```
var fs = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(_ImagePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
fs.Write(rBinarydata);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Is your app running as a default app pool user?

Comment: Yes, my app running as a default app pool user

Comment: then it doesnt count as "everyone" as the user you are running is a local account not a domain account

Comment: what is your suggestion for this?

Comment: set it as a domain user...

Comment: This is not a programming issue, you just need to set your permissions correctly. You can read online about configuring your IIS application pool to set the account it runs under. There are some built in ones, the MS documentation explains the implications of each, or you can create a specific service account for it and give it exactly the permissions required.